# Add custom value to access policy with iam.PolicyDocument in cdk

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-cdk, identity-management

I am creating a new iam.PolicyDocument and attach this to an CfnQueue SQS that I have created. But I couldn't find a way to add Id to the access policy. Here is my Policy document and I would like to add Id to the policy so I can see as in the screenshot in aws console but I don't know how to add this. I am using Typescript and aws cdk v2

```
addFifoQueueResources(queueName: string, isFifo: boolean, iscontentBasedDeduplication: boolean, accountId: any, region: any) {
  const cfnQueue = new sqs.CfnQueue(this, queueName, {
    queueName: queueName,
    fifoQueue: isFifo,
    delaySeconds:0,
    contentBasedDeduplication: iscontentBasedDeduplication,
    maximumMessageSize: 262144,
    messageRetentionPeriod:345600,        
    receiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds:0,
    visibilityTimeout: 30
  });

  const customPolicyDocument = new iam.PolicyDocument({
    **//I would like to add Id: sqspolicy-${queueName} here**
    statements: [
        new iam.PolicyStatement({
            actions: ['SQS:*'],
            effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            sid: `Sid-${queueName}`,
            principals: [
              new iam.ArnPrincipal(`arn:aws:iam::${accountId}:root`)
              ],
              resources: [
                `arn:aws:sqs:${region}:${accountId}:${queueName}`
            ]
        })
    ]
});

new sqs.CfnQueuePolicy(this, 'customPolicyDocument', {
  queues: [cfnQueue.attrQueueUrl],
  policyDocument: customPolicyDocument.toJSON()});}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems, they do not support the `id` for it, at the moment

More info here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.PolicyDocumentProps.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer but you are talking about the id of the statement, i am talking about the id of the policy. I have already added sid inside the statement